# Is it safe to use double quote to initialize string as using generic algorithm in C++?

Tags: c++, string, generics, compiler-construction

I am studying the C++ Primer 5th edition. On page 479, it mentions that

> `string sum = accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), "");` is not correct since `no + on const char*` for "";

The type of `v` is a sequential container such as a vector.

I found that using double quotes to create a string is dangerous, especially for the condition that you use generic algorithm, since it requires the objects' defined operator.

But I can't figure out what the description `no + on const char*` means?

1. Will it call the constructor `string (const char* s);` which is defined in c-string?
   I think that's what the compiler does as it interprets the string which are initialized with quotes in C++.
2. Should we create a string with double quotes? It will cause `overriding on operators` failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What it's saying is that you can't add pointers to [const] char to each other, nor can you add a `char` to a `char [const] *` (well, technically, you can add a char to a `char *`, but it won't do what you want--it'll basically treat the `char *` as if it points to the beginning of an array, and treat the `char` as an index into that array, so the result will be a `char *` offset by some distance from the original, where the distance is equal to the encoded value of the char you added).

`std::accumulate` deduces the type it should use for the summation from the type of the value you pass as the third parameter. It tries to add things using that type, then when it's done, it attempts to return that value (then, in this case the assignment would attempt to convert `char const *` to `std::string`). That final conversion would work fine, but the intermediate additions would not.

To make it work, you need to pass an actual `std::string` as the initial value:

```
string sum = accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), string());
```

This way it will deduce the summation type as `std::string`, so it'll be adding items to a string instead of trying to add to a `char const *`. If you're compiler is new enough, you could get the same effect with:

```
string sum = accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), ""s);
```

C++11 added a "user defined literal" feature that allows a suffix like this to invoke a constructor for an object type. C++14 added a number of predefined suffixes like this, including 2 that use the `s` suffix like this--this one (for a string literal) creates a `std::string`. The other (for integers) creates a timing value used with the `std::chrono` timing classes/functions, so `3s` means "three seconds".

Comment: Is `std::string str("");` the same as `""`? Will that create a string `object`?  What's the difference between `std::string str("");` the same as `""`?

Comment: No, `""` gives a type of `char const *`, where `std::string("")` (obviously enough) gives a type of `std::string`. The *contents* are basically the same (empty string in both cases) but the types are different.

Comment: As far as I know is that the `""` returns a `const char pointer` like
declaring `"NoArgumentsAboutVotesPlease"`. Only as I assign it to the constructor of a `string` class can generate a string object with operator `+`. Thus, I can use the additional operator. Is that right?

Comment: @Stallman: Creating a string instead of a pointer is what allows addition to do what you want. However, (to use your example) `"NoArgumentsAboutVotesPlease"+5` and `"NoArgumentsAboutVotesPlease"+'\7'` are both perfectly acceptable expressions (that yield pointers 5 and 7 characters from the beginning of the string literal respectively).

Comment: But they still can't be taken as the third argument for `accumulate(~, ~, third argument);`, right? I must pass "~" to a string object, creating a string object.

Comment: You need to pass some type for which `x + y` is defined, where `x` is the type you passed as the third parameter, and `y` is the type referred to by the iterators you passed as the first and second. Assuming `v` is a `vector<char>`, `vector<char *>` or `vector<string>`, then yes, `string` would be the obvious choice.

Comment: Just a note, in order to use the `operator"" s` UDL you have to do a little more work. i.e. you have to do `using namespace std::literals::string_literals;` before using them to bring them into the global scope.

Comment: @Rapptz: Both `literals` and `string_literals` are inline namespaces, so while that works, not quite all of it is actually necessary.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Well yeah, but I believe you still have to do a `using` statement. Either that one or `using namespace std::string_literals;` would do.

Comment: @Rapptz: I wouldn't recommend it, but just `using namespace std;` *would* work as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I found that using double quotes to create string is dangerous

This is nonsense. There's no way in which it is "dangerous" to use string literals. In fact, using double quotes is pretty much the *only* way to create string literals, short of initializing each character separately in an array. And that is *way* more broken.

> `no + on const char*` for "";

I have no idea what this means, either. I doubt it's a quote out of the book or your compiler's error messages.

I *think* what it's trying to say is that there is no `+` operator defined for string literals. That is true. They are just pointers to an array of characters. You can only overload operators for class objects. That's the advantage of `std::string`—you can concatenate string objects using the `+` operator.

If you want a string object, you will need to create one:

```
std::string myString("Hello");
```

You can concatenate two of those:

```
std::string myOtherString("World");
std::cout << (myString + myOtherString) << std::endl;
```

To answer your questions, if you want a string object, you should create one. You do not, however, always need a string object. Sometimes a C-style string literal is perfectly acceptable. It is foolish to make "rules" about what you should or should not do. It is actually quite rare that a normal application concatenates strings like this.

Comment: Is `std::string str("");` the same as `""`? Will that create a string 'object'?

Comment: So must I create something like this: `string("chars"`?

Answer (score 0):

const char* is just a pointer to a C style array, if you try and use the + operator on 2 of them it won't compile.

Answer (score -4):

String literal `""` has type `const char [1]`. Passed to the algorithm it is adjusted to type `const char *`

Inside the algorithm there is used `operator +`. However this operator is not defined for adding two objects of type `const char *`. So the compiler shall issue an error.
If inside the body of the algorithm there is used an object of type `std::string` then the problem will be with the assignment statement because there is no assignment operator for objects of type `const char *` that accepts objects of type `std::string` as the right operands.

So it seems you should write the call of the algorithm the following way

```
string sum = accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), string() );
```

And the author of the book meant this when it said that **"no + on const char***
That is if there are two pointers for example

```
const char *p = "Hello ";
const char *q = "World";
```

you may not write

```
q + p
```

Comment: Sorry, but no. `operator +` most certainly *is* defined for `char const *` (it's called pointer arithmetic)--it just doesn't do what you want in this case.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin  There is no operator + for pointers. Please read the C++ Standard.

Comment: Good advice. You might try taking it yourself. §5.7/1: "For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type, or **one operand shall be a pointer to a completely-defined object type and the other shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type.**" [emphasis added]

Comment: @Jerry Coffin For such "advanced" as  you I repeat THERE IS NO OPERATOR + for pointers. There is only operator -. Read one more the Standard because it is obvious it is not enough to read the standard one time for you.

Comment: "Inside the algorithm there is used `operator +`. However this operator is not defined for objects of ty[e `const char *`. So the compiler shall issue an error.". This fragment there implies there aren't **any** operators defined for `const char*`, while there is in fact `operator+` defined. So this should instead of "there is no `operator+`" say "there is no `operator+` that adds two `const char*`s"

Comment: @milleniumbug There is a big difference between "operator + for objects of type const char *" and "operator * for objects of type const char * and objects of integral type" Operator + is a binary operator. So you have to specify types of both operands. So my answer is totally correct and clear.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: You actually quoted the fact that `operator+` only exists for two cases: 1) Both operands are arithmetic (or unscoped enum) type. 2) One of the two is a pointer type and the other is integral or unscoped enum type. None of those two points indicates that both operands may be pointers or that addition is defined for both operands being pointers.